# Fulfilment for 'en' local when msg from telegram

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram-bot, google-assistant-sdk, fulfillment

I write a telegram bot, I use Dialogflow and [Dialogflow Fulfillment Library](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) . When I receive messages from telegram the Dialogflow Fulfilment Library always recognize messages on `en` local (`agent.locale` always return `en`). No matter what a language I use in messages. I write the message on Cirillic, but on the server I get local `en` and `intent` recognize like `en`. How Dialogflow recognize locale for request and how can I change local on `ru` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you have implemented. If I understand correctly you expect Dialogflow to automatically detect language. For the API V2 I noticed that you have to specify `language_code` explicitly. This makes sense, since some user system could start classifying poorly if the intents are defined in language A and some input is falsely interpreted as language B. This could occur if users do use language A, but include borrowed words ('computer' is also a Dutch word for example) or use names (for example, 'Where is Berlin Hauptbahnhof?')

For API v2 it seems you can try to set `agent.locale` in `v2-agent.js`.